# How to alter a column's attribute using sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How can I alter a column's attribute using a sql script?

Here's what I've tried but I got errors:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblBiometricPattern] COLUMN BiometricPatternID TINYINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Here's the error message that appears when executed:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN'.
```

Comment: i would seriously question how wise creating an IDENTITY on a tinyint is

Comment: Identity on a tinyint is a no-no.
Basically it's either a really small table, and you're better off managing the ID yourself (to keep consistent across deployments and such), or it's a large table, and then tinyint is just, well, tiny!

Comment: It just happen that I just wanted to try it on a different data type. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to alter the column so that it's an IDENTITY column... you can't do that. You can add a new column with the identity property, but you can't alter an existing column.

If that's not what you're trying to do, perhaps you could *include the actual error messages* you're getting.

---

The general form for altering an existing column is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblBiometricPattern] ALTER COLUMN BiometricPatternID TINYINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

(that is, you were missing the word "ALTER" before COLUMN). But as I say, this will now return an error telling you that you can't change the IDENTITY property of the column.

---

If the column is *already* an identity column, and you're just altering the datatype, then leave off the IDENTITY() property. It will still be an identity column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblBiometricPattern] ALTER COLUMN BiometricPatternID TINYINT NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the information Damien_The_Unbeliever. I've already included the error message on the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter/modify column of a table.

For MySQL / Oracle (prior version 10G):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

For Oracle 10G and later:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name datatype;
```